# Access Matplotlib and Scipy documentation within Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

Numpy provides a `np.info` function which allows to access the documentation of any function of this module. I am looking for a similar function for Scipy and Matplotlib. I would like to access these documentations without having to pull up a web browser.

Comment: On Jupyter notebook, use help(). For example, help(np.info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can simply use the Python built-in [`help`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=help#help) function as follow

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
help(plt.plot)
```

which returns

```
plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs)
    Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.

    Call signatures::

        plot([x], y, [fmt], *, data=None, **kwargs)
        plot([x], y, [fmt], [x2], y2, [fmt2], ..., **kwargs)
...
```

You can also use this function in an interactive mode, from the documentation:

> Invoke the built-in help system. (This function is intended for interactive use.) If no argument is given, the interactive help system starts on the interpreter console. If the argument is a string, then the string is looked up as the name of a module, function, class, method, keyword, or documentation topic, and a help page is printed on the console. If the argument is any other kind of object, a help page on the object is generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.info` on every function that has docstring, i.e. `np.info(plt.plot)` will print

```
In [10]: np.info(plt.plot)
 plot(*scalex, **scaley)

Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.

Call signatures::

    plot([x], y, [fmt], *, data=None, **kwargs)
    plot([x], y, [fmt], [x2], y2, [fmt2], ..., **kwargs)
...
```

Also most IDEs (or even text editors that are intended to develop in) provide some way of accessing the documentation without having to print docstring. In Jupyter it's Shift-Tab in parenthesis, in PyCharm it's Ctrl-Q, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Though using `help` and `np.info` work perfectly fine, I tend *not* to use these in practice. Instead, I prefer to use IPython's `?`, as such:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: plt.plot?
Signature: plt.plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs)
Docstring:
Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.

Call signatures::

    plot([x], y, [fmt], *, data=None, **kwargs)
    plot([x], y, [fmt], [x2], y2, [fmt2], ..., **kwargs)
...
```

This has a few of advantages over using `help` or `np.info`:

1. Speed: `plt.plot?` is faster to type than `help(plt.plot)` or `np.info(plt.plot)`
2. For functions wrote in python there is also `??` which reveals the source code of the function.
3. Pretty printing: `?` output adds a little colour which helps aid readability.

The only disadvantage of using `?` instead of `help` is that `?` is an IPython feature, and so won't work in a vanilla python console. It will, however, work in Jupyter, Spyder and from Ipython directly.